# DefaultIfEmpty mess ordered items in EF and LINQ to Entities?

Tags: entity-framework, linq

Given this entity (and this records as examples)

```
Discount
Amount Percentage
1000          2
5000          4
10000         8
```

I want to get the percentage to apply to one P.O. Amount

I.E.: Having a P.O. Amount of 15000

if I use

```
db.Discount
  .Where(d => d.Amount <= PO.Amount)
  .OrderByDescending(o => o.Amount)
  .Select(s => s.Percentage)
  .ToList()
  .DefaultIfEmpty(0)
  .FirstOrDefault();
```

I get 8 (correct)

but if I use

```
db.Discount
  .Where(d => d.Amount <= PO.Amount)
  .OrderByDescending(o => o.Amount)
  .Select(s => s.Percentage)
  .DefaultIfEmpty(0)
  .FirstOrDefault();
```

I get 2 (incorrect) and items are not ordered any more.

Am I doing an incorrect use of DefaultIfEmpty?

Comment: Why do you need `DefaultIfEmpty`, the `FirstOrDefault` itself return `default` value. Also, give some input on `PO.Amount`.

Comment: @Selva TS This is true but I'm wondering if it is true that DefaultIfEmpty messes ordered items to not use it anymore in other scenarios

Comment: No, I think, in the first one, the `ToList()` executes the query and returns value then  get the value. But in the second one, overall the query runs and return the value. Possible check the SQL query formed for both statements.

Comment: Are you using Entity Framework or EF Core? And SQL Server or something different?

Comment: You could try with `db.Discount.Where(d => d.Amount <= PO.Amount).OrderByDescending(o => o.Amount).Select(s => s.Percentage).Take(1).DefaultIfEmpty(0).FirstOrDefault();`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Entity Framework 6.*, then it is a [known bug](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework6/issues/167):

> the workaround is to move the DefaultIfEmpty call to after the ToList, which is arguably better as there is no need for the replacement of an empty result set to be done in the database.

Following examples generated with EF 6.1.2 (and "captured" with Microsoft SQL Profiler on a Microsoft SQL Server 2016).

Now... Your "wrong" query:

```
var res = db.Discounts
    .Where(d => d.Amount <= PO.Amount)
    .OrderByDescending(o => o.Amount)
    .Select(s => s.Percentage)
    .DefaultIfEmpty(0)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

"removes" the `OrderBy`:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
    [Limit1].[C1] AS [C1]
    FROM ( SELECT TOP (1) 
        CASE WHEN ([Project1].[C1] IS NULL) THEN cast(0 as bigint) ELSE [Project1].[Percentage] END AS [C1]
        FROM   ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable1]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN  (SELECT 
            [Extent1].[Percentage] AS [Percentage], 
            cast(1 as tinyint) AS [C1]
            FROM [dbo].[Discount] AS [Extent1]
            WHERE [Extent1].[Amount] <= @p__linq__0 ) AS [Project1] ON 1 = 1
    )  AS [Limit1]',N'@p__linq__0 bigint',@p__linq__0=15000
```

**"best" query would be:**

```
var res = db.Discounts
    .Where(d => d.Amount <= PO.Amount)
    .OrderByDescending(o => o.Amount)
    .Select(s => s.Percentage)
    .Take(1)
    .ToArray()
    .DefaultIfEmpty(0)
    .First(); // Or Single(), same result but clearer that there is always *one* element
```

See the `Take(1)`? It generates a `TOP (1)`:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT TOP (1) 
    [Project1].[Percentage] AS [Percentage]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        [Extent1].[Amount] AS [Amount], 
        [Extent1].[Percentage] AS [Percentage]
        FROM [dbo].[Discount] AS [Extent1]
        WHERE [Extent1].[Amount] <= @p__linq__0
    )  AS [Project1]
    ORDER BY [Project1].[Amount] DESC',N'@p__linq__0 bigint',@p__linq__0=15000
```

Then the `ToArray()` will move the elaboration to C#. You could use `.FirstOrDefault()` with `??` instead of using `DefaultIfEmpty()`, but the result would be different if `Amount` is already nullable (the `null` returned by `FirstOrDefault()` is because there are no rows or because the only row found has `Amount == null`? Who knows :-) ). To solve this problem it becomes a little more complex (in the most general case):

```
var res = (db.Discounts
    .Where(d => d.Amount <= PO.Amount)
    .OrderByDescending(o => o.Amount)
    .Select(s => new { s.Percentage })
    .FirstOrDefault() ?? new { Percentage = (long)0 }
).Percentage;
```

Here the `(long)` in `(long)0` should be the data type of `Percentage`. This query gives:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT TOP (1) 
    [Project1].[C1] AS [C1], 
    [Project1].[Percentage] AS [Percentage]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        [Extent1].[Amount] AS [Amount], 
        [Extent1].[Percentage] AS [Percentage], 
        1 AS [C1]
        FROM [dbo].[Discount] AS [Extent1]
        WHERE [Extent1].[Amount] <= @p__linq__0
    )  AS [Project1]
    ORDER BY [Project1].[Amount] DESC',N'@p__linq__0 bigint',@p__linq__0=15000
```

Other "worse" variant:

```
var res = db.Discounts
    .Where(d => d.Amount <= PO.Amount)
    .OrderByDescending(o => o.Amount)
    .Select(s => s.Percentage)
    .Take(1)
    .DefaultIfEmpty(0)
    .First();
```

that gives an overcomplicated query with two `TOP (1)`:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
    [Limit2].[C1] AS [C1]
    FROM ( SELECT TOP (1) 
        CASE WHEN ([Project2].[C1] IS NULL) THEN cast(0 as bigint) ELSE [Project2].[Percentage] END AS [C1]
        FROM   ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable1]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN  (SELECT TOP (1) 
            [Project1].[Percentage] AS [Percentage], 
            cast(1 as tinyint) AS [C1]
            FROM ( SELECT 
                [Extent1].[Amount] AS [Amount], 
                [Extent1].[Percentage] AS [Percentage]
                FROM [dbo].[Discount] AS [Extent1]
                WHERE [Extent1].[Amount] <= @p__linq__0
            )  AS [Project1]
            ORDER BY [Project1].[Amount] DESC ) AS [Project2] ON 1 = 1
    )  AS [Limit2]',N'@p__linq__0 bigint',@p__linq__0=15000
```

Answer (score 1):

this is normal because

for first statment

```
db.Discount.Where(d => d.Amount <= PO.Amount).OrderByDescending(o => o.Amount).Select(s => s.Percentage).ToList().DefaultIfEmpty(0).FirstOrDefault();
```

you call **.ToList()** before **DefaultIfEmpty(0)** which means when you call .ToList() statment translated to sql as following

```
DECLARE @p0 Int = 15000
SELECT [t0].[Percentage]
FROM [AppScreens] AS [t0]
WHERE [t0].[Amount] <= @p0
ORDER BY [t0].[Amount] DESC
```

then executed and loaded in memory after that these two function run on data in memory `.DefaultIfEmpty(0).FirstOrDefault();` so the result is as you expected

but for second statment

```
   db.Discount.Where(d => d.Amount <= PO.Amount).OrderByDescending(o => o.Amount).Select(s => s.Percentage).DefaultIfEmpty(0).FirstOrDefault();
```

you don't call .ToList() which mean that statement won't be executed until it reach  **FirstOrDefault()** because **DefaultIfEmpty(0)** function is implemented by using deferred execution and you can read its documentation from this reference of [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355419(v=vs.110).aspx)

When it reach **.FirstOrDefault()** statment translated to sql as following

```
DECLARE @p0 Int = 15000
SELECT  case when [t2].[test] = 1 then [t2].[Percentage] else [t0].[EMPTY] end AS [value]
FROM (SELECT 0 AS [EMPTY] ) AS [t0]
LEFT OUTER JOIN ( SELECT TOP (1) 1 AS [test], [t1].[Percentage] FROM [Discount] AS [t1] WHERE [t1].[Amount] <= @p0 ) AS [t2] ON 1=1 
ORDER BY [t2].[Amount] DESC
```

then executed and loaded in memory after that so the result isn't as you expected
because it get **top 1** first before **order** so it get first item.